# how to create two vnets and some subnets in each one of those VNETs using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

how to create two VNETs and some subnets in each one of those VNETs dynamically using terraform?

Currently, I'm creating four separate resources 2 each for VNETs and subnets.

I wanna use just one resource block for VNET and one resource block for the subnet in the tf code and have terraform pick for say VNET "test" two subnets (test1-subnet, test2-subnet) and second VNET say "dev" two separate subnets (dev1-subnet, dev2-subnet).

How to achieve this scenario using terraform for azure provider?

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "rest-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name  = "test-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example1" {
  name                = "test-network"
  address_space       = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name  = "test-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "rest-subnet"  
  resource_group_name  = "test-rg"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"

  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example1" {
  name                 = "test-subnet"  
  resource_group_name  = "test-rg"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example1.name
  address_prefix       = "10.1.1.0/24"

  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **parametrize** your setup. One way, could be as follows (example which you may need to modify to suit your specific need):

```
variable "vnets" {
    default = {
        test = {
          address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
          resource_group_name  = "test-rg"          
          subnets = [{
              address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"
          },
          {
              address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
          }             
          ]
        },
        dev = {
          address_space = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
          resource_group_name  = "dev-rg"          
          subnets = [{
              address_prefix       = "10.1.1.0/24"
          },
          {
              address_prefix       = "10.1.2.0/24"
          }             
          ]
        }
    }
}


locals {
    # flatten the var.vnets variable
    vnet_subnet_map = merge([
           for vnet_name, vnet_details in var.vnets:
            {
                for idx, subnet in vnet_details.subnets: 
                    "${vnet_name}-${idx}" => {
                        vnet_name = vnet_name
                        subnet_name = "${vnet_name}${idx}-subnet"
                        address_space = vnet_details.address_space
                        resource_group_name = vnet_details.resource_group_name
                        subnet_address_prefix = subnet.address_prefix
                    }
            }
        ]...) # do NOT remove the dots
}
```

Then you create the two vnets and their subnets:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {

  for_each            = var.vnets

  name                = "${each.key}-network"
  address_space       = each.value.address_space
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
}



resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  
  for_each             = local.vnet_subnet_map

  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = each.value.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[each.value.vnet_name].name
  address_prefix       = each.value.subnet_address_prefix

  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}
```